# Raster projection is inverted Python-GDAL

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am carrying out a program that, based on the data from weather stations, performs an interpolation and generates a georeferenced raster with these data.

The program works well interpolating and saving the raster, however, the projection of the raster is inverted.

[image]

This is the image of how the raster is stored, the green dots are the location of the weather stations, which should coincide with the vertices of the raster image.

I know that interpolation works well because when I use Matplotlib to visualize the image it looks like this:

[image]

Because of this, the problem must be when I do the raster projection that corresponds to this part of the code:

```
#Saving raster
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = [xi.min(),yi.min(),xi.max(),yi.max()]
nrows,ncols = np.shape(zi)
xres = (xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres = (ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres) 

output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('myraster.tif',ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)  # Open the file
output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)  # Specify its coordinates
srs = osr.SpatialReference()                 # Establish its coordinate encoding
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)                     # This one specifies WGS84 lat long.

output_raster.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )   # Exports the coordinate system 
                                               # to the file
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(zi)   # Writes my array to the raster

output_raster.FlushCache()

output_raster= None
```

I've been modifying the program for a long time and I can't find the problem, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Matplotlib plots things with the origin in the bottom left by default, as is standard in mathematics.  Of course that differs from geospatial imagery which uses the top left.  You have the negative Y resolution as you should, just [flip the array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) before you save it

Comment: WOW, Thank you very much, I was a week in this, I was very tired of this topic and I could not think of anything else.